# String format works in fprintf but doesn't work in sprintf, gives segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, printf

```
fprintf(fp,"IP: %d:  %.*s\n",
        ip, 
        strstr(strstr(p->data, "User-Agent:"),"\n") - strstr(p->data, "User-Agent:"),
        strstr(p->data, "User-Agent: ") );
    fclose(fp);
```

Hi All, as you can see, in the above statement, I am trying to write off just the User Agent header from a char pointer which contains the entire http packet data. The thing is, After fiddling with the string format, I came up with this %.*s format which lets me, dynamically select the number of characters to be printed to the file, and then prints them. What the code is basically doing is, first, it's printing an int, then the number of chars from the occurrence of "User-Agent:" to the very next occurrence new line character is passed, and that amount of chars are then passes starting at where the "User-Agent:" starts, from the entire packet data string. I know it's all pretty messy, but it's working fine. Except that it's not working in sprintf.

Please save all my hard word! Any help is appreciated!

```
    char *stat;
    sprintf(stat,"%.*s\0",
        strstr(strstr(p->data, "User-Agent:"),"\n") - strstr(p->data, "User-Agent:"),
        strstr(p->data, "User-Agent: ")) ;
```

Comment: Shame on you for calling the same `strstr` 3 times with the same arguments. You know, it's a rather expensive function.

Comment: @Jan: but then again, premature optimisation is the root of all evil. A better argument for not writing copy-and-paste code like this is that it is less robust and harder to maintain.

Comment: @Paul R: Yes, maintainability is a good argument too. And as of "premature optimisation", well, premature optimisation is something that the code more complicated for sake of unproven benefit, but this would be making the code simpler and more readable.

Comment: Why not something like: `char *ua_start = strstr(p->data, "User-Agent: "); char *ua_end = strchr(ua_start, '\n'); sprintf(stat, "%.*s\0", ua_end-ua_start, ua_start);` (untested).

Comment: If you fix this code not to crash when the header is malformed, it will require even more slow, ugly, visually-bulky calls to `strstr` to make the checks. For Cthulu's sake, PLEASE just make some proper temp vars to store the needed positions/lengths!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not allocating memory for `stat`. Try

```
char *stat = malloc(MAXLEN);
snprintf(stat, MAXLEN, ...);
 ^              ^
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use sprintf, you need an array of characters to write into.  You're writing to an uninitialized pointer.

Try this instead:

```
char stat[200];
sprintf(stat, etc...
```

Comment: I thought an array was the same thing as a char pointer, as far as passing it to functions was concerned. That's why I did it the way I did, but I realized it, and finally corrected it. And this is exactly how I did it, even chose the same number (200).

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are trying to write the data into uninitialized unallocated random memory location. Now that can't possibly work.

Either do:

```
char stat[SUFFICIENTLY_LARGE_NUMBER];
snprintf(stat, SUFFICIENTLY_LARGE_NUMBER, ...);
```

or:

```
char *stat = malloc(SUFFICIENTLY_LARGE_NUMBER);
snprintf(stat, SUFFICIENTLY_LARGE_NUMBER, ...);
```

and make sure "SUFFICIENTLY_LARGE_NUMBER" is enough bytes that the string fits in and not unnecessarily huge.

PS: snprintf, because your format does not include length limits. If it does, `sprintf` is OK, but never ever use `sprintf` with unlimited `%s`. Your `%.*s`, while formally limited, is not enough, because the expression will happily return more than the size of the allocated buffer, so you need another check to avoid overruning it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and sprintf and snprintf. I never knew snprint even existed. Thanks for the help!